# Extracting readable text from HTML using Python?

Tags: python, html, text-extraction

I know about utils like html2text, BeautifulSoup etc. but the issue is that they also extract javascript and add it to the text making it tough to separate them.

```
htmlDom = BeautifulSoup(webPage)

htmlDom.findAll(text=True)
```

Alternately,

```
from stripogram import html2text
extract = html2text(webPage)
```

Both of these extract all the javascript on the page as well, this is undesired.

I just wanted the readable text which you could copy from your browser to be extracted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to avoid extracting any of the contents of `script` tags with BeautifulSoup,

```
nonscripttags = htmlDom.findAll(lambda t: t.name != 'script', recursive=False)
```

will do that for you, getting the root's immediate children which are non-script tags (and a separate `htmlDom.findAll(recursive=False, text=True)` will get strings that are immediate children of the root).  You need to do this recursively; e.g., as a generator:

```
def nonScript(tag):
    return tag.name != 'script'

def getStrings(root):
   for s in root.childGenerator():
     if hasattr(s, 'name'):    # then it's a tag
       if s.name == 'script':  # skip it!
         continue
       for x in getStrings(s): yield x
     else:                     # it's a string!
       yield s
```

I'm using `childGenerator` (in lieu of `findAll`) so that I can just get all the children in order and do my own filtering.

Comment: @demos, you're welcome, glad to hear this!  BTW, why the accept (and btw tx for it!) without an upvote?  Seems strange!-)

Comment: @Alex Martelli The first upvote is from me. What a pity that there hasn't been any upvote on this answer for 19 months !

Answer (score 0):

Using BeautifulSoup, something along these lines:

```
def _extract_text(t):
    if not t:
        return ""
    if isinstance(t, (unicode, str)):
        return " ".join(filter(None, t.replace("\n", " ").split(" ")))
    if t.name.lower() == "br": return "\n"
    if t.name.lower() == "script": return "\n"
    return "".join(extract_text(c) for c in t)
def extract_text(t):
    return '\n'.join(x.strip() for x in _extract_text(t).split('\n'))
print extract_text(htmlDom)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can remove script tags in beautiful soup, something like:

```
for script in soup("script"):
    script.extract()
```

[Removing Elements](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Removing%20elements)

Comment: Looks like a quick solution, but what is the penalty for tag extraction?

Answer (score 0):

Try it out:

http://code.google.com/p/boilerpipe/

http://ai-depot.com/articles/the-easy-way-to-extract-useful-text-from-arbitrary-html/