# How to get only text of a webpage with Python, just as Select-all & Copy in browser?

Tags: python

I want to get "Main content" instead of < tag> Main content , where the latter is html code and could be retrieved using urllib.urlopen(url).

Just as you open the url in browser, select all text and then copy&paste.

Is there a possible way for this with Python?

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172343/extracting-readable-text-from-html-using-python

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

> Beautiful Soup is a Python HTML/XML parser designed for quick turnaround projects like screen-scraping. Three features make it powerful:
>
> 1. Beautiful Soup won't choke if you give it bad markup. It yields a parse tree that makes approximately as much sense as your original document. This is usually good enough to collect the data you need and run away.
> 2. Beautiful Soup provides a few simple methods and Pythonic idioms for navigating, searching, and modifying a parse tree: a toolkit for dissecting a document and extracting what you need. You don't have to create a custom parser for each application.
> 3. Beautiful Soup automatically converts incoming documents to Unicode and outgoing documents to UTF-8. You don't have to think about encodings, unless the document doesn't specify an encoding and Beautiful Soup can't autodetect one. Then you just have to specify the original encoding.